# Unable to load/require any css files in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have a ReactJS application based off of this [boilerplate](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example).

I am simply trying to load and `require` or `import` a css file (to be embedded in `<style>` tag, as opposed to css link). Below are the two methods I have tried, and not ever both at the same time.

### **Method 1:** Configure loaders in Webpack

These are all the loader configurations I have tried, but still resulted in this error: `[require-hacker] Trying to load "something.css" as a "*.js"`

**dev.config.js**

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      // loaders in here
    ]
 }
```

1. `{ test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }`
2. `{ test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'}` from [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader)
3. `{ test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css!postcss' }`
4. `{ test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css?modules&localIdentName=[name]---[local]---[hash:base64:5]!postcss' }`
5. `{ test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
            }
          }
        ]
      }`
6. `{
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style!css?modules&importLoaders=2&sourceMap&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version!sass?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap'
   },`

### **Method 2:** Use loaders directly

If I remove the css loaders altogether, and instead call `require('style!css!./something.css')`, I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'style!css!./something.css'
```

---- # **NOTE:**  ----

I am able to properly `require` my `.scss` files and its webpack loader configuration is below. But for some reason my css files don't want to play that way too.

```
    { test: /\.scss$/, 
      loader: 'style!css?modules&importLoaders=2&sourceMap&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version!sass?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change extensions: ['less','scss'] to extensions: ['less','scss','css'] in webpack-isomorphic-tools.js at line 65.for more details you can see [this](https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/webpack-isomorphic-tools)